# Creating a visual indicator graph that separates returns into high, normal and low

Tags: python, matlab, dataframe

I have another thing that's stumping me. As context, I'm using historical data using the Stock ticker QQQ from 2005 to 2011.

I'm currently trying to create a semblance of a graph that visually depicts cumulative returns into high, normal, and low. I'll attach a picture of the intended graph below. I have the cumulative returns calculated, and that's no issue, but I'm completely at a loss as to how to visually classify the numbers I get in my dataframe into visual representations like the graph shown below.

My code showing the cumulative returns is below, just as a good sense of showing how I have calculated those numbers.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('QQQ2.csv')

df['ret'] = df.prc.pct_change()
df['log_ret'] = np.log(df.prc/df.prc.shift(1))
df['growth_vol'] = df.vol.pct_change()

df['cumulative_ret']=np.exp(df['log_ret'].rolling(60).sum())-1
ret1 = df['cumulative_ret']
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFZ1.jpg

Thanks in advance if any help is offered.

Comment: You didn't show a picture of the intended graph.

Comment: Woops! just added an Imgur link. Sorry about that.

Comment: You want to color code the background according to the value right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

As you did provide the tag for matlab, I will provide a solution that I came up with.
[image: Example of Code Output]

```
yRange = [-0.5 1]; % Min and max y axis values

x = datenum('Jan-13-2020'):datenum('Jan-13-2021'); %general xdata
y = sin(2.*pi.*x)/2+rand(1,length(x))-0.5; %random y data
z = zeros(size(x)); %preallocation
 
thresh = 0.2; %Threshold for 'normal'

z(y>thresh)  = 1;
z(y<-thresh) = -1;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,yRange); %create grid points
Z = ones(size(X)); %preallocation
Z = Z.*z; %dot multiply each row with the z vector

%Create a surface below our data
surf(X,Y,-ones(size(X)),Z,...
    'EdgeColor','none',...
    'FaceColor','interp')

%Change the surfplot colors
colormap([1 0.5 0.5;... %Light Red
          1 1 0.5;...   %Light Yellow
          0.5 1 0.5])   %Light Green

%Plot data on top
hold on
plot(x,y,'-k',...  % plot the data 
    'LineWidth',2)
yline(0,'--k')     % Plot the '0' line
hold off

%Change the plot limits
xlim([x(1),x(end)]) 
ylim(yRange)

view([0 0 1]) % Look along the z-axis (x-y plane)
```

I am sure something similar can be created with the matplotlib library.